# How to get rid of log4j 1.2.17 jar in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

I am using spring boot version 2.1.5.Release, am trying to remove log4j 1.2.17 jar tried exclusion logic.inside spring boot starter dependency it's not worked. Could you please help me to fix the log4j issue. I tried upgrade of Spring boot version still I see dependency in my eclipse under maven dependencies..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you do not have the logging starter for log4j. If not, then in the dependency hierarchy in eclipse, right-click on log4j and it will let you exclude it from whatever is pulling it in as a transitive dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Looks like the esapi dependency I use is having log4j vulnerable jar. I commented it and I don't see it anymore

Comment: You're welcome, good to know.